# onError is not called when Maybe receives null

Tags: java-8, reactive-programming, rx-java2, rx-android

I am learning how to use Maybe observable. I created the below example. Incase of

```
Maybe.just(value) I will receive the value in onSuccess callback.
```

In case of Maybe.just(null), I expected to receive the log from onError. However, according to the posted code, when I run the code, the App crashes and I do not receive any logs.
Would you please tell me why I am not receiving any logs from onError()?

**code**

```
Maybe.just(null)
            .subscribe(
                    i->Log.i("TAG:", "[onSuccess]: " + i),
                    err->Log.e("TAG", "[ERROR] err.getMessage(): " + err.getMessage()),
                    () -> Log.i("TAG", "[COMPLETED]: ")
         );
```

Comment: Because Maybe#just [throws a `NullPointerException` if its argument is `null`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/3481ed1eee9bbdda77435d2c5f698c714ea2fea3/src/main/java/io/reactivex/Maybe.java#L891), those logging statements never get a chance to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a `Maybe` doing `Maybe.just(null)`. It will throw a `NullPointerException`, that's why your app crashes.

Some people suggested that the library should have the option to [Create a Maybe from null in RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5019), but unfortunately that won't happen:

> Closing as won't happen. Static methods returning RxJava types can live on any external class.

A workaround for doing that, is to replace this:

```
Maybe.just(null)
```

For this:

```
Maybe.fromCallable(() -> null)
```